# Magento backend throwing lock_wait_timeout error with Galera cluster

Tags: magento, mariadb, galera, magento-2.3

We have recently moved our Magento database from GCP cloudsql to Galera Cluster.Front end is working fine where in backend we are getting lock_wait timeout error for any change from backend. We noticed this happens after importing any huge product change fro sheet.

error:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query was: UPDATE `catalog_product_entity` SET `attribute_set_id` = ?, `type_id` = ?, `sku` = ?, `has_options` = ?, `required_options` = ?, `created_at` = ?, `updated_at` = ? WHERE (entity_id = '12132')

Has anybody comeacrsoss this kind of issue or any optimization recommendation ??

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE catalog_product_entity` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%lock_wait%'`, and look for other things going on at the same time.

Comment: innodb_lock_wait_timeout : 1800
lock_wait_timeout : 86400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated below parameters and the issue got resolved.

```
innodb_autoextend_increment=512
thread_concurrency = 45
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_thread_concurrency = 47
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=1800
```